# Proxying AppSync calls to a REST datasource in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-appsync

We have a React site connecting to AppSync with a REST datasource. The REST datasource is inside a VPC. We need to be able to proxy calls to the VPC and AppSync doesn't support (as far as I know) integration with private VPCs.

What's the best way to proxy calls from AppSync to an internal REST service behind a VPC. I could use API Gateway because it does support private VPCs (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/) but then we would have to create endpoints for each method whenever a method is added to the REST service which seems tedious and unneeded if all we're doing is proxying calls. We could use a Lambda to proxy calls but that seems like overkill as well.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkB didn't see that before. Thanks! I don't know how to mark a comment as an answer but thanks

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "but then we would have to create endpoints for each method whenever a
>   method is added to the REST service which seems tedious and unneeded
>   if all we're doing is proxying calls."

Not with [HTTP PROXY integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) in API Gateway, it will just proxy whatever requests it gets to the backend.